# Protractor can't catch mat-dialog-container

Tags: angular, protractor, e2e-testing

My Protractor test for an Angular 5 application works fine until it needs to catch popup with input fields, the popup element is

```
<mat-dialog-container class="mat-dialog-container ng-tns-c26-5 ng-trigger ng-trigger-slideDialog ng-star-inserted">
```

I've tried browser waits, browser sleeps, my code currently is:

```
await element(by.id('mat-dialog-container')).to.eventually.equal(true);
browser.waitForAngular();
browser.sleep(60 * 1000); 
await element(by.id('mat-input-1')).sendKeys('A value');
await element(by.id('mat-input-2')).sendKeys('A value');
```

Watch the catch when catching mat-dialog popups?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The id of an element is not it's tag-name. Extend your HTML and add an id. Then try again.

```
<mat-dialog-container id="mat-dialog-container" class="mat-dialog-container ng-tns-c26-5 ng-trigger ng-trigger-slideDialog ng-star-inserted">
```

The same with your mat-inputs

```
<mat-input id="mat-input-1"></mat-input>
<mat-input id="mat-input-2"></mat-input>
```

Comment: Thank you! So, the Angular tag-names are not catchable at all then, something like element(by.tagName('mat-dialog-container')) is not meant to work?

Comment: Actually, `by.tagName()` also exists. I thought you want to use `by.id()` only. :) Please have a look at this link. https://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=webdriver.By.tagName

Comment: PS: If this helped it'd be kind if you could mark my answer as solution.

Comment: by.tagName was something I tried, but didn't work, any more ideas?

Comment: Unfortunately not. If by.tagName() fails, by.id() is the safest way.

Comment: I will improve the html with my developer in the hope that adding ID works, as for now, I will mark your anwser as a solution. Thanks!